# IE not catching Enter key for form submission

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a simple form with one text box that pass data to SQL and I want it to submit when the user hits the enter key.

In Firefox, this works great. The user puts a number hits enter gets back the results.

However in IE 8 and IE 9 this is not working.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" accept="cmdclick" 
style="background-position: center; background-image: url('BG.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div style="text-align: center">
<br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txttrack" runat="server" Height="20px" 
        Width="175px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>  
    <asp:Button ID="cmdclick" runat="server" 
        CommandName="cmdclick" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None"  />
```

I am not sure what would cause this. I see a lot of people using JavaScript to go around the problem however I do not know how to write JavaScript code.

How can this be done (preferably without JavaScript)?

Comment: This really shows nothing. What about your vb code that drives the cmdclick? Also, what part of it exactly is "not working" in IE8/9?

Comment: It showed enough for Tim to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx)-Property in Form-Tag:

```
<form defaultbutton="cmdclick" runat="server">
```

You can also set the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) on ASP.NET-Panels. This might not be important in this case but

- when you're using MasterPages, because the ID of a Button in a ContentPage is unknown in a MasterPage (Form-Tag is inside the Masterpage)
- when you want to have more than one DefaultButton you can set different DefaultButtons to every Panel

Comment: Its worth noting too that Panel controls also have a DefaultButton property. So if you have different text boxes on your page that should response differently to an "enter", then you can wrap the text boxes in seperate panels and set each DefaultButton property

Comment: @icemanind:Thats correct, i've edited my answer to consider this aspect.

Comment: Thanks Tim cant believe I missed something so small appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If you have recursive form elements (which is against standards compliance) then IE will basically ignore the enter key and not submit the form when it is detected as it doesn't know which form you are trying to submit.